# Clarification on a statement of a theorem

Tags: uniform-continuity

If $f(x)$ be continuous over $(0,1]$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ exists.

I have a question about this statement, I am unclear on whether if it is saying that $f$ is uniformly continuous only over $(0,1]$ or is it everywhere, where $f$ is defined? Thanks!!!

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be the Conway Base-13 function. It is a function that is discontinuous everywhere. Now, define $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x \in [0,1] \\ g(x), & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ It should be clear that $f(x)$ satsifies both conditions, but is nowhere continuous on $(-\infty,0)$ or $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Only over $(0,1]$.  As far as you know, that's the *only* set on which $f$ is “defined.”

Answer (score 1):

Only over $(0,1]$; since you don’t know anything about the function elsewhere, that’s the only place you know it’s uniformly continuous.